# Moving legend outside of plot area (Vegan package)

Tags: r, plot, legend, vegan

I'm trying to use vegan package in R to create NMDS plots for my research. I'm having problems placing the legend in the correct area, however. The legend always covers some of the points and gets cut off by the outline of the plot. Anyone have any ideas of how I could format the legend outside of the plot area, or move it so that it doesn't cover up any points?

[Here is an exported image of what my graph looks like now, with part of the legend missing and covering up some points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do7mD.jpg)

Here is the script I've been using:

```
op <- ordiplot(nmds, type = 'n')
cols = c('darkred', 'darkgreen', 'darkblue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'black')
points(nmds, cex = 2, pch = 16, col = cols[coral_ENV$Year])
ordispider(nmds, groups = coral_ENV$Year, label = TRUE, label.size = 0.2)
ordihull(nmds, groups = coral_ENV$Year, lty = 'dotted')
legend("topleft", inset = 0.03, pch = 16, col = cols, text.width = 0.05, legend = levels(coral_ENV$Year))
```

I'm pretty new to R so I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Try the `inset` parameter in `legend()`.

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide a reproducible sample? Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example